# Object Array group by two value field and map result

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to group a javascript object array by 2 different value field and then map the result to my linking.
source:

```
[{"date":"2012-05-01","casinoName":"Grand Orient Casino","type":"Other","number":"68"},{"date":"2012-06-01","casinoName":"Grand Orient Casino","type":"Free Coins","number":"11"},{"date":"2012-06-01","casinoName":"slotCasino","type":"New Game","number":"40"},{"date":"2012-07-01","casinoName":"Slotomania","type":"Other","number":"17"}]
```

result expected:

```
[{"date":"2012-05-01","Grand Orient Casino Other":"68"},{"date":"2012-06-01","Grand Orient Casino Free Coins":"11", "slotCasino New Game":"40"},{"date":"2012-07-01","Slotomania Other":"17"}]
```

So what am I doing?
I am mapping the casinoName and type value together as my key and my value is the value of number. Then I am grouping them by the date.
I am having issue as having something efficient doing that.
Any help would be welcome.

Comment: `var result = SourceArray.map(function(itm){ var ob = {date:itm.date}; ob[itm.casinoName] = itm.number; return ob;  })`

Comment: The solution you give in your question seems good enough. How big is your source data? If it's less than 100(1000/10000/...) elements, then it may be better to use your solution that you understand, than a solution found on SO which will be 3ms more efficient.

Comment: @PSL the point is that I don't want to iterate once to map and again to group. I am dealing with potential thousand of objects and I want to be as efficient as possible. Volune, thanks for your answer but I believe this data manipulation can actually be pretty performance dragging. I could do it on the server (php) but I'd need some help to make it efficient as well.